# Can exclamation and interrogation marks be used at the same time?

Tags: puntuación, símbolos

I have read and seen many Spanish exclamatory and interrogative sentences on the internet.

But all of them were exclusively exclamatory, or exclusively interrogative.

I have never seen a sentence to be both interrogative and exclamatory.

For example, we have:

> ¿De verdad estás bromeando?
>
> ¡Oh Dios mío!

Now, do we have this kind of sentence too? :

> ¡¿De verdad estás bromeando?!

Comment: There's even a punctuation mark that does this, [the interrobang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrobang): _"⸘De verdad estás bromeando‽"_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, they can!** 
Both signs can be combined, even mixed without being paired-up.

> — ¿¡Sabiás que la RAE dice que los signos de interrogación y exclamación se [admiten en distintas combinaciones en el idioma español](https://www.rae.es/dpd/interrogaci%C3%B3n)!?
>
> — ¡Por qué será que no explotamos esas posibilidades expresivas?

Check this other question which addressed the same topic in this site [Is a mixture of exclamation mark and question mark accepted practice, or was it a typo?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17012/is-a-mixture-of-exclamation-mark-and-question-mark-accepted-practice-or-was-it/17015#17015)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how about the order? You wrote the exclamation mark first "!?". But shouldn't the question mark come first? "?!"

Comment: Either order is acceptable. I quote them: `b) Cuando el sentido de una oración es interrogativo y exclamativo a la vez, pueden combinarse ambos signos, abriendo con el de exclamación y cerrando con el de interrogación, o viceversa: ¡Cómo te has atrevido? / ¿Cómo te has atrevido!; o, preferiblemente, abriendo y cerrando con los dos signos a la vez: ¿¡Qué estás diciendo!? / ¡¿Qué estás diciendo?!`